# Integrate codeigniter app into wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, view, integration

I´ve been looking for some help in different sites, hope I can find it here. I have developed a web application using codeigniter, and the client wants to integrate it into it site which has a wordpress installation. The site has some pages like contact, blog, platform...

The application has a login/sign up screen and works with sessions.

So what i´m trying to do is to put the codeigniter code into the wordpress file system and be able to access to the application into the wordpress domain. Right now is something like this:

---

```
WP Dir/
   wp-content/
   ...
   ...
   codeigniter dir/
      httpdocs/
         application
         views
         ...
```

httpdocs/
           application
           views
           ...

---

So wordpress is working, but when I try to go into www.webpage.com/codeigniterDir/login trying to log into the application, the page is almost empty, only has the wordpress header and footer. Hope u guys can help me, ty!

Comment: You are probably confusing WP and CI route. Instead You can use CI in WP Root folder.